# Where can I find information about Soviet Union arrests in the 1930s?

Tags: 20th-century, russia, 1930s

One of my ancestors was arrested and killed in the purges of the 1930's in the Soviet Union. I've heard of people who got papers from the Russian (post Soviet) government containing the "crimes" they were accused of and the interrogation they were subject to,

Where can I find this data? Is it online?

Comment: Just you need to dig FSB(post KGB) archives.

Answer (score 5):

You can try to look for this data in FSB archives. They were declassified in 2007.
http://www.russialist.org/archives/2007-150-34.php

Comment: Are they available online?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. You have to send a request by mail (it seems it's possible to send a request by email as well). There is a long thread on one of Russian genealogical forums (forum.vgd.ru) about that, you can look it up. http://forum.vgd.ru/447/22429/0.htm

Answer (score 3):

Memorial community collects information about political arrestants from USSR and places information [here](http://lists.memo.ru/) in alphabetical lists of surnames. One can try to look through lists and find ancestor's names.